# Cart price rule issue for uses per customer

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules

[image]

I am using Magento ver. 2.4.3 and I have created the coupon code with following configuraion:

1. uses per coupon - 1
2. uses per customer - 1

Expected result:

1. The coupon should be valid only once for success order for particular customer.

Issue:

1. We are able to use same coupon for particular user for multiple times.

Please help us with same issue.

[image]

Comment: Are you testing it with logged in customers or guests? With guests shouldn't not work.

Comment: yes. I have tested with logged in customer but the same issue raised

Comment: see https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/4410911888013-Coupon-for-single-use-is-used-multiple-times-Adobe-Commerce, also make sure your crons are running

Comment: yes. crons are running but issue remains same

Answer (score 2):

I found this Link while searching for my own coupon usage issue
https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/4410911888013-Coupon-for-single-use-is-used-multiple-times-Adobe-Commerce

It relates to "Adobe Commerce (all deployment methods) 2.4.3 and above" so this might be your issue OP

The solution, in case the link goes dead the way Magento documentation enjoys doing, is "Add the sales.rule.update.coupon.usage consumer to the app/etc/env.php file."

```
...
    'cron_consumers_runner' =>
    array [
        'cron_run' => true,
        'max_messages' => 20000,
        'consumers' =>
        array [
            'sales.rule.update.coupon.usage'
        ]
    ],
...
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

rabbitmq installed and with its account;
Run this command too before placing next order - bin/magento queue:consumers:start sales.rule.update.coupon.usage &

Answer (score 0):

**Affected products and versions**

Adobe Commerce (all deployment methods) 2.4.3 and above

**Issue**

Merchants set up a coupon for single use and customers are able to use it multiple times.

**Cause**

Merchants do not have sales.rule.update.coupon.usage consumer set up and running that results in improper behavior.

**Solution**

Add the sales.rule.update.coupon.usage consumer to the app/etc/env.php file.

```
...
    'cron_consumers_runner' =>
    array [
        'cron_run' => true,
        'max_messages' => 20000,
        'consumers' =>
        array [
            'sales.rule.update.coupon.usage'
        ]
    ],
...
```

Run this command - `bin/magento queue:consumers:start sales.rule.update.coupon.usage &`