# Magento 2 : Cart price rule issue for uses per customer not working

Tags: magento2.3

Magento 2: Cart price rule issue for uses per customer not working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cart price rule issue for uses per customer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/351842/cart-price-rule-issue-for-uses-per-customer)

Answer (score 0):

I am using Magento ver. 2.4.6 and I have created the cart rulewith percentage  with the following configuration:

Uses per customer - 1

**Expected Result:**

The rule should be valid only once for success order for particular customer.

**Issue:**

We are able to use same rule for particular user for multiple times.

**Reference from Adobe**

URL:https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-knowledge-base/kb/troubleshooting/miscellaneous/coupon-code-used-more-than-once-adobe-commerce.html?lang=en

**The solution**

Add the sales.rule.update.coupon.usage consumer to the app/etc/env.php file.

```
'cron_consumers_runner' =>
array [
    'cron_run' => true,
    'max_messages' => 20000,
    'consumers' =>
    array [
        'sales.rule.update.coupon.usage'
    ]
],
```

And Run below command

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento cron:run (for local instance)

php bin/magento c:f

I hope it is useful for you.